# Are there keyboard shortcuts to zoom in a Google Document?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

In the top left of Google Docs is the zoom amount - default is 100%. 
Is there a way to increase this size - aside from using the browser's zoom (ctrl and "+" or mousewheel).

Comment: I note Google's own keyboard shortcuts list omits some useful ones, e.g. ctrl + alt + shift + z / x / c   to go to edit / suggestions / viewing modes respectively.

Comment: Comments should not be used to add additional information to a question. Instead you should edit your question and add it to it. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment to lear more about comments.

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for this as well and did some digging. Google Docs now has keyboard shortcuts to zoom in and out of the document (and not the webpage itself).

The shortcuts are:

Zoom in: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on Mac

Zoom out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> on Mac

I found these in the **Help** → **Keyboard Shortcuts** → **Search keyboard shortcuts** (you can type anything here). Strangely enough, the official Google Docs Keyboard Shortcut page (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738) makes absolutely **no** mention of this at all. Weird. Anyway, below is screenshot showing the info in Google Docs.

I'm guessing these are possibly newer keyboard shortcuts since the official Google Docs page doesn't even list them and other people have struggled with this issue for many years, including me. Makes me wanna search that Help section even more now and find other hidden gems.

Hope this helps!

[image: Zoom Google Docs Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: It doesn't appear that Google supports a zoom outside of the browser window zoom (command + '+' and command + '-')
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: True. The shortcuts described in this answer don't exist (anymore). The Keyboard Shortcuts search too shows nothing. Even the mentioned keyboard shortcuts have been assigned different actions.

Answer (score 4):

Well that's a design *faux pas*, isn't it? Having something on a shortcut button that's not also in a menu?

Anyway, after perusing the [extended keyboard shortcut list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738), the closest thing I've found is:

1. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to open the "search menus" option
2. Type <kbd>Z</kbd> to bring up a bunch of options, including all of the "zoom" options
3. Use the arrow keys to move to the value you want and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: search menus with zoom options]

Comment: It works with an English keyboard layout. It doesn't work with an Italian keyboard layout unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

On my keyboard it's: <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> OR <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: I struggled a lot with this topic and your answer saved me! I use Ubuntu 22.04/Google Chrome and CTRL + ALT + = zommed in, and CTRL + ALT + - zoomed out!

Answer (score 0):

2022 answer

The only 'native Docs' zoom options are located in the View, under Zoom. You just can't, for example, just zoom to 80% because it isn't listed.

For more fine-grained zoom options, you're forced to use the browser's zoom feature. Some browsers (for sure [Firefox](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues), but possibly Chrome too) support configurable zoom steps using the about:config page.